# Adding NFS mounted file systems on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, 14.04, mount, fstab, nfs

Is there something special that needs to be done to make sure NFS file systems are mounted at boot time with 14.04?

I added some NFS mounts to /etc/fstab  in a virtual server running Ubuntu 14.04, but when I rebooted the VM, it did not mount the file systems.  I added the line:

```
mount -vat nfs
```

to rc.local, but that is a hack.  Do I need to do something else to let the system know it needs to mount some NFS file systems?  On CentOS machines, merely adding lines to /etc/fstab always works, but I am new to Ubuntu and maybe I need to do some additional thing.

The /etc/fstab file looks like this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/vda1 during installation
UUID=ef6d9c40-9035-4452-b091-8b68d7a2cbee /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/vda5 during installation
UUID=0da4579e-f3a9-4ab3-8818-0cc1cd559a8d none            swap    sw              0       0
192.168.1.251:/home            /home       nfs    rw,hard,intr,nfsvers=3,tcp,,defaults        0 0
192.168.1.251:/distros            /distros       nfs    ro,hard,intr,nfsvers=3,tcp,,defaults        0 0
192.168.1.251:/var/spool/mail /var/spool/mail       nfs     rw,hard,intr,nfsvers=3,tcp,,defaults        0 0
newserver:/UbuntuMirror /UbuntuMirror nfs rw,hard,intr,nfsvers=3,tcp,,defaults        0 0
```

The host server is running CentOS 6.5 and yes, all of the NFS file systems are properly exported.

Comment: Is the network coming up in time? I have only needed to use `mount -a` when there were network problems.

Comment: Yes, the network comes up just fine.  This is a virtual machine on a virtual network.

Comment: At some point I googled up an undocumented mount option `_netdev` that you're supposed to add to /etc/fstab to tell Ubuntu's `mountall` to wait until the network is available before attempting to mount this.  This may or may not help.